# Default Value for Dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using JavaScript for an editable table in Bootstrap. Three of the columns are dictated by dropdown values. When the values are "saved" they are converted into their proper text values, but I'm having trouble keeping their saved dropdown choices as the "default" when they come back to edit.

For example:
They enter '3' in their dropdown and save it. If they want to go back and edit (likely another field in the table), the dropdown that once held 3 now goes back to the default of 1.

Here's my code for edit:

```
function Edit() { 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
    var tdDate = par.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
    var tdCellNum = par.children('td:nth-child(2)');
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");                 
    tdDate.html("<input type='date' id='txtDate' value='"+tdDate.html()+"'/>"); 
    tdCellNum.html("<select id='txtCellNum'><option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option></select>");
    tdButtons.html("<img src='save.png' class='btnSave'/>");
```

Any idea on how to get the value from `tdCellNum` to display as the default in the dropdown?

I've tried setting the value of `select =tdCellNum and tdCellNum.val` and using Number to convert the object to a number.I've also tried setting a `var=tdCellNum` with the rest of the variables, then `document.getElementById("tdCellNum").value=copyValue.html();` along with `tdCellNum.val=copyValue` but all to no avail.Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to create the element and append it. This way you can use .val() to select the option.

```
var sel = $("<select id='txtCellNum'><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option></select>");
sel.val(tdCellNum.text());
tdCellNum.empty().append(sel);
```

Comment: Now when I press edit, it doesn't run anything. Should I be configuring the tdCellNum.html or changing anything in that line of code (line 7)?

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Did you put this code in your function and get rid of the `tdCellNum.html("<select...);` line?

Comment: No I commented it out. Should I not have? And I'm also a new coder and not really sure how to view the console? I'm running it directly on the live site.

Comment: Google: Developer console [browser name]

Comment: AH CRAP MY BAD!!! Edited the code above. Typo on my part. I forgot to wrap it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tdCellNum.text()` to get the value in the field.

Then you could do:

```
tdCellNumInt=tdCellNum.text();
tdCellNum.html("<select id='txtCellNum'><option value=1>1</option> <option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option></select>");
tdCellNum.find("option[value='"+tdCellNumInt+"']").prop("selected",true);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still seem to be getting the default value of 1. Is there anyway tdCellNum is like an object or a type that can't be used that way? Not really sure of the technical terms (new coder)